# Client Object Model Javascript intellisense

Tags: web-part, client-object-model

I created a new test.js file in the project node of my web part solution with VS 2010 and included the references:

```
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MicrosoftAjax.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\SP.Core.debug.js" />
```

I then proceeded to write a basic test.

```
function test() {
    this.Cli
```

I stopped at the letter i.  I was hoping IntelliSense would prompt me with **ClientContext** and help me along.  This does not happen.  Is this by design?  I am following Microsoft procedures here for stand alone .js files.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798328.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the path to MicrosoftAjax.js was incorrect.  It turns out that the Ajax tools were buried in a few places under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7...  Perform a search for the file and then copy it to the LAYOUTS directory with the others.  Then perform Ctrl+Shift+J to refresh the library.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the JavaScript Intellisense by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J ? Restarting Visual Studio should also help.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I should be more clear. IntelliSense is popping up, but doesn't offer what I expect.  ClientContext is not in the list of options. Thanks.